# Set Intellij IDEA JPA Console naming strategy

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I have an all-default (excepts Lombok) Spring Boot 2.5.6 + PostgreSQL project with a very basic JPA mapping open in Intellij IDEA 2021.2.3. JPA configuration is implemented with annotations (no XML). The app itself works fine, records get saved and retrieved from the DB. In "Persistence" window I can see my JPA structure correctly, datasource is assigned. Here is the entity code:

```
@Entity
@Data
...
public class Cover {
...
private String ageRestriction;
}
```

But when I try to execute a query with e.g. `select c from Cover c` I get an error:

```
jpa-ql> select c from Cover c
[2021-11-01 16:14:03] [42703] ERROR: column cover0_.agerestriction does not exist
[2021-11-01 16:14:03] Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "cover0_.age_restriction".
```

I tried to add the naming strategy configuration to my settings but this had no effect:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

I don't see "Assign naming strategy" in the persistence unit context menu as well (see screenshot). Is there a way to force JPA Console to use the same naming strategy my app does?
[image: IDE UI]

**PS:** I've managed to make the console work after specifying `@Column` for all multi-word field names and adding @Table annotation with `schema` and `name` properties. But I would prefer to be able to sync console and app JPA/Hibernate configurations somehow.

Comment: Did you select your JPA provider in `Project Structure` > `Modules` > `your module` > `JPA` > `Default JPA Provider` ?

Comment: @gmanjon yes, there was Hibernate selected.

Comment: Did you try with a previous version of Intellij IDEA? Removing *.iml/.idea/target/? Invalidating caches?

Comment: 1) IDEA 2020 doesn't see a secondary entity linked through @Embedded so I couldn't even get to the same point 2) I don't have such a folder 3) Yes, no effect

Comment: Sorry. Run out of ideas without more info. May be with the whole project structure (folders), a screenshot of the "Project Structure" IDEA window we can come up with something.  Did you try removing the `@Embedded` and tried a project with simple JPA mappings? The thing that this dis't work well innprevious versions sound suspicious (may be pointing to that direction).

Comment: The project structure is nothing more than a standard Spring boot setup. 
[link](https://gcdn.pbrd.co/images/0PYOFKTSiVlO.png)
Entities are shown correctly in the persistence window.
I don't think it has something to do with `@Embedded` because the field IDEA is wrongfully generating name for is a plain String field in the parent entity.
[link](https://gcdn.pbrd.co/images/5WBxnVf8gCiN.png)
But I also tried JPA Console in the very beginning with just 5-6 persistent fields and a single `@Entity` with no @Embedded objects and used to get the same error.
Thanks for suggestions anyway.

Comment: Is it the IDEA ultimate or the community edition?

Comment: Ultimate (I believe Community Edition doesn't offer the Persistence tab and JPA Console)